# Android Facebook Api v2.4 - How to get comments and likes?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get comments and likes(name,profile picture,like count of comments etc.) but it is not working. I looked for older questions but they are all related with older versions of API. Theye are not working anymore. I am reading [this document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/object/comments). It says I can get them buy simply `{post-id}/comments` but it is not working at all.This is what I do and what I get:

[image]

I cannot get anything but id.
I really appreciate if anyone knows it and shares with me.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:I also tried "post-id/comments" request too.It is not working too.

Comment: You need to specify which fields you want

Comment: For comments:Name,profile_picture,created_time,like_count_of_comment,like_link_of_comment,comments_of_comment,like_link_of_comments_of_comment.
For likes:Name,profile_picture.
Shortly,same with facebook. When I specify these,it changes nothing.Still getting only id.

Comment: What do you get when you request the post only (without using fields)? Perhaps you do not have the necessary permissions to read that content?

Comment: If I only request the post-id,I get id,created _time and message.

Comment: I cannot get an answer even in stack?? I should be right about facebook api is broken! Btw,documentation is really weak.Learning android is so much simpler than using facebook api.If anyone think I am wrong,then prove it and I will shut up and thank for the solution.